# PHP preg_replace won't work

Tags: php, regex

So as far as I know, I have done this exactly as prescribed I should do, but PCRE makes absolutely no sense to me at all, so I am going to ask you what is wrong with this code and why does it say:

> missing terminating ] for character class at offset 10 in

```
  $UrlTeams = preg_replace(
    array(
        "/[\/\\\40][\\]?/",
        "/[\.%]/",
        "/\&/"
    ),
    array(
        "/\-/",
        "",
        "\&amp\;"
    ),
    $UrlTeams
  );
```

Comment: i dont think you need to escape those characters when they are inside a characterclass `[]`... what exactly are you trying to find and replace?

Comment: @prodigitalson, I am trying to find /, \ or spaces coupled with a maybe/maybe not \ in the first one and replacing it with a -.
The second one is . or % replaced with nothing.
The third is & replaced with &amp;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$UrlTeams = preg_replace(
    array(
        "#[/\40\\\\][\\\\]?#",
        "#[.%]#",
        "#[&]#"
    ),
    array(
        "-",
        "",
        "&amp;"
    ),
    $UrlTeams
  );
```

Comment: +1 It's so much clearer when you don't use slashes as the pattern delimiter and can go without so much escaping

Comment: @prodigitalson, With that setup I get: "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 9 in"

Comment: @prodigitalson, thanks a lot, that worked. Now why is it that I have to do a tripple escape?